# Android: Move a view along with finger

Tags: android, touch

I have some views which are created at runtime and added to `FrameLayout`. The views can be moved `onTouchEvent`. So far, I am able to move the views. But, they are not moving properly. I mean, for the first time, when they are moved, they move alongwith finger. But, when they are moved for the second time, the distance between finger and the view increases and they are moved to someother point other than where the finger points. I am not getting where did I made mistake. Below is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

    boolean result = v.onTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        Log.e("CircleTest", "ACTION_DOWN");
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v
                .getLayoutParams();

        deltaX = X - params.leftMargin;
        deltaY = Y - params.rightMargin;

        // Save the ID of this pointer
        mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            break;
        }
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        Log.e("CircleTest", "ACTION_MOVE");
        final int pointerIndex1 = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex1);
        final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex1);

        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v
                .getLayoutParams();

        params.leftMargin = X - deltaX;
        params.topMargin = Y - deltaY;

        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        break;
    }
    default:
        return result;
    }
    main.invalidate();
    return false;
}

//**main** refers to the frame layout in which views are added.
```

Comment: use this link. i think it will help you.
[linke here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817292/how-to-animate-button-with-finger-ontouch-event-android

Comment: It's hard to get where you made a mistake without a code. Debug it. I'm pretty sure the source of the problem are your class-member variables which you constantly reuse in this method. For example, `deltaX, deltaY, mPosX, mPosY`. They're declared in the class scope. Maybe you're modifying them somewhere else outside of `onTouch(..)` method